# Updating Relay store after Graphcool sign in

Tags: graphql, relayjs, graphql-js, graphcool

As part of my webapp's authentication flow, I managed to create a User in my Graph.cool backend, and now need to sign in (this is a 2-step process as discussed [here](https://github.com/graphcool/dashboard/issues/294)). This uses the `signinUser` mutation, which I've set up successfully [here](https://github.com/sedubois/belong/blob/gql-auth/app/relay/mutations/SignInUserMutation.js). However, I couldn't figure out how to configure the mutation's `getFatQuery()`/`getConfigs()`, so that the viewer user data would be properly updated in the Relay store and propagated. For example, the page header (`ViewerWidget`) doesn't get auto updated, but displays the correct information if I reload the page.

Answer (score 2):

Relay tracks all the data requirements of components that are (or were) rendered. When a mutation is sent, it also queries all of the data that might change (given through the FatQuery) and that is tracked. In other words, if your mutation's FatQuery contains nodes/fields that aren't tracked by Relay yet, they won't be included in the mutation's query (as the component's that need that data would just simply request it, when rendered for the first time).
`REQUIRED_CHILDREN` forces the mutation to query for certain fields, even when they are not tracked. It's really just an escape hatch for cases where you need to handle data outside of Relay. It's to Relay as `ref` is to React.

The graphcool API gives you a viewer root field with an ID. It should be possible to have a `FIELDS_CHANGE` mutation (with the viewer ID) for the field user.